# Proof for linearity on tensor products

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, duality-theorems

> Theorem:
>   Let $U$ and $V$ be vector spaces. Let $\mathbf{u}^* \in U^*$. Define $\mathbf{f} : U \otimes V \to V$:
>   $$\mathbf{f}\left(\sum_{r} \mathbf{u}_r \otimes \mathbf{v}_r\right) = \sum_{r} \mathbf{u}^*(\mathbf{u}_r) \mathbf{v}_r$$
>   Then $$\sum_{r} \mathbf{u}_r \otimes \mathbf{v}_r = \sum_{r} \mathbf{u}_r' \otimes \mathbf{v}_r' \Rightarrow \mathbf{f}\left(\sum_r \mathbf{u}_r \otimes \mathbf{v}_r\right) = \mathbf{f}\left(\sum_{r} \mathbf{u}_r' \otimes \mathbf{v}_r'\right)$$

How to prove this theorem? I tried to use the fact that $\otimes$ is bilinear:
\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{f}\left(\sum_{r} \mathbf{u}_r \otimes \mathbf{v}_r\right)
 &= \sum_{r} \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{u}_r \otimes \mathbf{v}_r) \\
 &= \text{I don't know what would be here} \\
 &= \sum_{r} \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{u}_r' \otimes \mathbf{v}_r') \\
 &= \mathbf{f}\left(\sum_{r} \mathbf{u}_r' \otimes \mathbf{v}_r'\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Are you familiar with the universal property of tensor products?

Comment: @Amitai Yuval Yes that was a typo. I changed it. Thank you.

Comment: @HenryW : Is there some guide to MathJax on this site or elsewhere that told you to use \mbox{} instead of \text{}? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: As it stands, I don't understand what this theorem is claiming. It seems to say $a=b$ implies $f(a)=f(b)$. The only non-trivial part is the existence of $f$, but this does not seem to be the claim you are trying to prove?

Comment: @moonlight $\mathbf{f}$ is defined in a way that it extracts the operand $\mathbf{u}_r$ from an operation $\mathbf{u}_r \otimes \mathbf{v}_r$. Since the expression for a tensor $\sum_{r} \mathbf{u}_r \otimes \mathbf{v}_r$ is not unique, it is necessary to prove changing the combination does not change the value of $\mathbf{f}$.

Comment: It's a very strange way of stating this, but I see what you mean. I second Amitai Yuval's comment then. First define $f_0\colon  U \times V \to V$ with the rule you state (on the Cartesian product this is a priori a well defined function). Then verify bilinearity of $f_0$ and apply the universal property of tensor products.

Comment: Also, it's better not to think of $f$ as "extracting" $u_r$ from $u_r \otimes v_r$. You cannot "recover" $u_r$ from $u_r \otimes v_r$ since $u_r \otimes v_r = u_r\lambda \otimes \lambda^{-1}v_r$ for all nonzero $\lambda$ in your field.

Comment: @moonlight If $\mathbf{f}$ is applied on a tensor $\mathbf{u}_r \lambda \otimes \lambda^{-1} \mathbf{v}_r$, its definition $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{u} \otimes \mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{u}^*(\mathbf{u}) \mathbf{v}$ causes the two scalars $\lambda$ and $\lambda^{-1}$ to cancel each other. That is, $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{u}_r \lambda \otimes \lambda^{-1} \mathbf{v}_r) = \mathbf{u}^*(\mathbf{u}_r) \mathbf{v}_r$.

Comment: @HenryW: I understand this perfectly well, but I suggest not thinking of it as extracting $u_r$, because that is not the correct picture for tensor products, and will sooner or later lead to confusion. In any case, have you managed to make progress using the sketch we gave? Do you need further hints?

Comment: @moonlight Yes I have found a proof to this theorem.

Answer (score 0):

just define $f$ on cartesian product and use universal theorem to conclude it.